# How do you add a package repo and key to apt with saltstack?

Tags: debian, salt-stack, apt

I'm only a beginner with SaltStack. I can see there is a pkgrepo module that can be used to set up a package repo in order to install a package from it.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkgrepo.html

An example given there is:

```
base:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - humanname: Google Chrome
    - name: deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
    - dist: stable
    - file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome-browser.list
    - require_in:
      - pkg: google-chrome-stable
    - gpgcheck: 1
    - key_url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

What I do not understand is where do I put the above code? I tried in the /srv/salt/top.sls, and in other state .sls files there, but that is not right. How is it done?

Answer (score 12):

You basically want to know how to use SaltStack states. This is documented at https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/starting_states.html.

To test this code, you have to:

- create a new sls file containing the code, for example `testrepo.sls`
- execute this state with the `salt` command.

Example:

```
salt 'hostname.domainname' state.sls testrepo
```

where `hostname.domainname` is the name of the `minion` (saltstack client) you wish to configure, as reported by `salt-key`.

In the given examples, `base` is the state name. It must be unique. So `base` was a very bad choice to use in the docs, as it may confuse you with the top sls files syntax, documented here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html

So, in order to install google-chrome, to take your example, you'd create a state file like the following:

```
google_chrome_repository:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - humanname: Google Chrome
    - name: deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
    - dist: stable
    - file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome-browser.list
    - gpgcheck: 1
    - key_url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub

google-chrome-stable:
  pkg.installed:
    - require:
      - pkgrepo: google_chrome_repository
```

Note that I change the requisite declaration from a `require_in` to a `require` that have more sense here, in my opinion, if you have more than one package to install from this repository. Requisites are documented here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html